# Проблема в реализации оператора перегрузки

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, перегрузка-операторов, утечка-памяти

````
//здесь перегрузка оператора вывода
    template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &value)
{
    out << value;  // здесь я вызываю оператор вывода для объекта типа T, который хочу вывести
    return out;
//вот тут я пытаюсь вывести массив из структур
for (int i = 0; i < heap.sizeHeap;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<heap.heapArray[i];
    }

}```

но когда я отладчиком захожу в программу, он заходит в функцию перегружающую тот самый оператор,то она просто останавливается на строке
out << value;
и ничего не происходит. А когда включаю программу то вызывается ошибка сегментации, в чем проблема?
````

Comment: В первой строке реализации оператора вызывается сам оператор. Бесконечная рекурсия...

Comment: как тогда быть? перегрузить этот же оператор для конкретного типа данных?

Comment: Не ленитесь, поправьте форматирование в вопросе.

Comment: Тут явно какое-то непонимание. Почему у вас какой-то код после return? До него выполнение никогда не дойдет. Почему вы делаете `out << value`; не понимаете, что вы просто вызываете эту же самую функцию из самой себя? Почему у вас аргумент функции - любой тип? (`const T &`) Наверное там должен быть ваш класс?